# cocos2d sprite state after beeing applied a CCFadeOutBLTiles effect

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

What is happening to a sprite (or layer) after you apply something like a CCFadeOutBLTiles effect , it seems to be disapeared, how to get it visible to start using it again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `opacity` property to 255. Also make sure `visible` is set to YES.